# Chrome widget for eddystone-url in Android

Tags: eddystone-url

I got eddystone beacons which broadcast URL and I was able to see the eddystone URL in iPhone Today's widget and came to know that in android phones this feature will be available with Google Play services 7.8. My android phone has Google Play Services 7.8 but not able to receive eddystone-URL

Answer (score 2):

As Eddystone is still in the experimental stages you need to download Google's [Physical Web app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=physical_web.org.physicalweb).